# prove that if $A\cup X=E$ for any subset $A $of $E$ then $X=E$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be any set and $X$ a subset of $E$.
I want to prove that if $A\cup X=E$ for any subset $A $ of $E$ then $X=E$

I tried to prove it using double inclusion:

As $X$ is a subset of $E$ then it comes $X\subseteq E$
now let $x\in E$. As $A\cup X=E$ then $x\in A\cup X$;
it means $x\in A$ or $x\in X$...
the problem is that for $x\in A$ i don't really know how to continue the demonstration

Comment: Hint:  Take $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: i thought about this but is it not a particular case?

Comment: The assumption is that $A\cup X=E$ for any subset $A\in E$.  As $\emptyset$ is a a subset of $E$, then we must have $X=\emptyset \cup X=E$

Comment: @lulu .... or $A = X$.....

Comment: Or let $A \subset X \subset E$.  In that case $A\cup X = X$ and $A\cup X =E$ so $X=E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an extreme and unusual condition such as $A\cup X =E$ use the fact that that *is* extreme and unusual.  If $A \cup X = E$ *no matter* ***what*** $A$ is then for any $e\in E$ then $e \in A\cup X$ *even* if $e\not \in A$!

For example: Let $e \in E$.  And let $A = E\setminus \{e\}$ which is certainly a subset of $E$.  Then $e \in E=A\cup X$ so $e \in A$ or $e \in X$ but $e$ is *not* in $A$ so $e \in X$.  So $E \subset X$.  And $X \subset E$ so $X=E$.

Even better let $A = \emptyset \subset E$ then $A\cup X = \emptyset \cup X = X = E$.  Done!.

Or $X\subset E$.  So $X \cup X = X = E$.  Done.

Or by contradiction.  If $X \ne E$ but $X \subset E$ then there is $x\in E$ where $x \not \in X$.    Let $A$ be any subset not containing $x$.  Then $x \not \in A\cup X$ and so $A\cup X \ne E$.

Or just to beat a dead horse.

If $A\cup X = E$ for all $A\subset E$ then for any $x \in E\setminus X$ we have $x\in A\cup X$ but $x \not \in E$ so $x\in A$ so $E\setminus X \subset A$ for *every* subset $A$ of $E$.  But that's absurd.  Afterall $E \setminus X \not \subset X$ for example.

Comment: You could have $X=A^c\subset E$

Comment: "You could have X=Ac⊂E" For what purpose?  You *could* be you don't *have* to.  That's the point.  $A\cup X = E$ for *all* subsets of $E$.  Such condition means $\emptyset \cup X =X=E$ and $X\cup X = X =E$.  And $E\setminus X \subset A$ for all subsets so $E\setminus X = \emptyset$ as that's the only set that is subset of *all* subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$, so $A\cup X=X$..   Since $X$ is a subset of $E$, $A$ is also a subset of $E$.    The hypothesis $A\cup X=E$ implies $X=E$.